# Segmentation fault in pipe

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, stdio

Given the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    scanf("%s", buf);
    printf("----> %s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

which is executed as follows:

`grep ....| a.out`

or

`echo ....| a.out`

I get a `Segmentation fault` error. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from scanf man:
s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence  and  the  terminating null character ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

specifying maximum field width will prevent stack overrun

```
    scanf("%1023s", buf);
```

and to ensure stack no overrun on printf use memset:

```
    memset(buf,0,1024);
```

so, programm will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    memset(buf,0,1024);
    scanf("%1023s", buf);
    printf("----> %s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: memset is not needed since we can initialise arrays to 0 easily in C99-C11. It's also probably faster, but that depends on system implementation.

Comment: @thlgood: Why is this the accepted answer? This clearly didn't answer the question, whereas I found the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Whatever you are echoing or grepping must contain more than 1023 characters. (1024 - 1 for the null terminator.)

Instead of using `scanf`, use `fgets` and specify a size. Alternatively, use `scanf` but specify the field length. You can do `scanf("%1023s", buf);`. If there's more bytes available, you can always do it again to read in the rest.

Given your test input, you should not receive a segfault. I just tried it locally and it worked fine. If you are on Linux, since you wrote `a.out` instead of `./a.out`, depending on how your path is configured you may be running the wrong program (some sort of `a.out` in your bin folder?)

Comment: no..I run `echo 'This is'|a.out` it still got `Segmentation fault`

Comment: `fscanf` provides no more protection than `scanf`, it's just `scanf` using an explicit file handle rather than `stdin` - I think you meant `fgets` which _does_ have a limit on characters read.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever use `scanf` with unbounded strings. `fgets` provides a much safer alternative, especially if you provide an intelligent wrapper function like the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

I'm assuming that's just sample code here but, just in case it isn't, you can achieve the same effect with:

```
WhateverYourCommandIs | sed 's/^/----> '
```

without having to write your own tool to do the job. In fact, with `sed`, `awk` and the likes, you probably *never* need to write text processing tools yourself.